# Remove integer digits when formatting a number to a string

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-formatting

When formatting a number into a string, I can limit the characters after a decimal point with, e.g., `%.03f` (display three digits after the point), but how do I also remove all digits BEFORE the point?

For example, I'd like `100.943` to format to `".943"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way for you to do that would be to remove the number before the decimal point using math, or string manipulation after the fact, like `componentsSeparatedByString:@"."`

A simple math way of removing it would be:

```
float initialValue = 100.943f;
int beforeDecimal = (int)initialValue;
float afterDecimal = initialValue - beforeDecimal;
```

Comment: With this method I could skip the math part and simply extract a substring.  I was wondering if there was a format that could be used to do this automatically.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't think there is a way for you to format strings that way unfortunately.

Comment: For your future reference, here is a link to the NSString formatting guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: Going to mark yours as correct, as I believe there isn't a way to format either.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/), and set its [`maximumIntegerDigits`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-BCIGCIDB) to 0:

```
float f = 123.456;
NSNumber * nF = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:f];
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:nF]);
```

> 2011-11-23 18:36:59.138 NoIntegerDigits[21834:903] .456

Comment: Upvote for you...but it's still not really part of NSString stringWithFormat.  I ended up doing [resultString substringFromIndex:i]; once I determined where the '.' was.

Comment: `stringWithFormat:` is not designed to do intricate formatting tasks; it's just a quick way to get primitives into an `NSString`. The fact that specifiers such as `%.03` work is probably due to it being built on `sscanf`. If you have specific formatting needs, use a formatter object.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I guess i got your question now..

Here is another solution where you will get strings out of string only.

example:

```
NSString *floatAsString = @"123.456";
NSArray stringDivisions = [floatAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

Here what you will get in array is: 123 and 456 to separate string objects.
Once you get two separate strings, you can play with them.

This is what you needed ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do that,
Here is an example,

> Firstly convert your string to float value.
>
> float x = 102.943;
>
> int y = x;
>
> float ans = x % y;
>
> NSLog(@"\nx : %f \ny : %d \nans : %f", x, y, ans);

So the output will be:

> x : 102.943000
>
> y : 102
>
> ans : 0.943000

Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: Actually looking for a way to format the string output for a UILabel without the whole numbers, but thanks anyways.